# Repetitive code in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I find myself writing a lot of repetitive code in UITableView, especially for config panels spending much more time on it that it seems worth.

I was wondering if something like MonoTouch Dialog (http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Feb-23.html) existed in Obj-C.

Thanks!

Comment: I often find it difficult to use iOS and not violate DRY...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had good luck with [Sensible TableView](http://www.sensiblecocoa.com/). The support is excellent, should you have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could write code to create table views/hierarchies declaratively. Apple's Settings app, for example, has most of it's layout and presentation defined in plist files that are adapted to something `UITableView` can consume by `PSListController`.